# Python3 - recursively replace all keys with periods in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to clean up a nested dictionary before inserting it into Mongo.  Some of the keys in the dict have periods in them so I need to replace them with underscores.  Based on other posts I have seen I have come up with this (not working) code sample:

```
def get_recursively(search_dict):
    new_dict = {}

    for key, value in search_dict.items():

        if '.' in key or ' ' in key:
            new_dict[key.replace('.', '_').replace(' ', '_').lower()] = value


        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_recursively(value)
            for key2, value2 in results.items():
                new_dict[key] = dict(key2, value2)

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item)
                    for key3, value3 in more_results.items():
                        new_dict[key] = dict(key3, value3)
        else:
            new_dict[key] = value

    return new_dict
```

I am trying to make a new dictionary because when I tried to modify the existing dictionary I got an error about the dictionary changing during execution.

The code that is not valid (at least) is:
`dict(key2, value2)`

That is not valid syntax but hopefully shows my thought process at least.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, is this want you meant?

```py
def change_chars(string, chars, new_char):
    new_string = string
    for char in chars:
        new_string = new_string.replace(char, new_char)
    return new_string

def recursively_change_keys(obj, chars, new_char):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [
            recursively_change_keys(o, chars, new_char)
            for o in obj
        ]

    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {
            change_chars(key, chars, new_char): recursively_change_keys(value, chars, new_char)
            for key, value in obj.items()
        }

    return obj
```

So you just have to call it like `recursively_change(search_dict, [ ".", " " ], "_")`

Comment: Thank you.  This works for my data.  You were first to respond, too

Comment: The list comprehension in this code will not work properly if there are lists directly within other lists in the input (e.g. `{'x.y': [[{'foo.1': 'bar'}], [{'foo.2': 'baz'}]]}`).

Comment: @Blckknght I didn't know that could happen, thanks. I just edited my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import json

d = {
    "some.key": [
        {
            "key.1": {"a": 1},
            "key.2": 2,
            "key.3": {"key.4": [3, 4, 5], "key.5": 6},
        }
    ]
}


def transform(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k.replace(".", "_"): transform(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [transform(v) for v in d]
    else:
        return d


# pretty print the dictionary:
print(json.dumps(transform(d), indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "some_key": [
        {
            "key_1": {
                "a": 1
            },
            "key_2": 2,
            "key_3": {
                "key_4": [
                    3,
                    4,
                    5
                ],
                "key_5": 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```